# .NET 3.5- The type or namespace `Pipes does not exist in the namespace System.IO

Tags: c#, .net, mono, ubuntu-10.04

I'm using .NET 3.5 and  mono 2.2.1 for building an application that can be supported on ubuntu 10.04. Basically we are downgrading an application formerly built using .NET 4.0 to .NET 3.5. The application needs to use the namespace `System.IO.Pipes`. However I'm getting an error-

> The type or namespace `Pipes' does not exist in the namespace`
>   System.IO'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

I'm can't figure out whether the problem is with the mono version (2.2.1) or the .NET version(3.5) or the Ubuntu version (10.04).

Also, is there any substitute for using `NamedPipeServerStream`?

Comment: I think there is a `System.IO.Pipes` namespace in .NET 3.5. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes(v=vs.90).aspx I think the problem is the mono version

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the Mono changelog for System.IO.Pipes shows:

> 2009-08-18  Atsushi Enomoto
>
> - AnonymousPipeClientStream.cs, AnonymousPipeServerStream.cs,
>     NamedPipeClientStream.cs, NamedPipeServerStream.cs
>     PipeAccessRights.cs,......

And then checking the branch dates of Mono 2.x:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/remotes/origin/ --format='%(committerdate:short) %(refname:short)' | grep mono-2
2009-03-11 origin/mono-2-2
2009-05-06 origin/mono-2-4-1
2010-08-23 origin/mono-2-4-3
2011-03-23 origin/mono-2-0
2011-03-23 origin/mono-2-4
2011-03-23 origin/mono-2-4-0
2011-03-23 origin/mono-2-4-2
2011-03-23 origin/mono-2-6-4
2011-03-23 origin/mono-2-6-7
2011-05-06 origin/mono-2-8
2011-07-25 origin/mono-2-6
2012-03-19 origin/mono-2-10-8
2012-04-26 origin/mono-2-10-9
2012-11-16 origin/origin/mono-2-6
2013-10-21 origin/mono-2-10
```

**Thus Mono 2.2.1 (Between 2009-03-11 and 2009-05-06) does not contain that namespace that you require as it was not added until 2009-08-18.**